# Kinit with systemd in user mode

Tags: systemd, sshfs, kerberos

I have created a `keytab` file under the user home directory `$HOME/client.keytab`. The authentication cache file is in it's default location `/tmp/krb5cc_%U` (where %U is the UID). Now, I have this simple `systemd` `unit` file to launch the service, and get authentication keys:

```
[Unit]
Description=Initializes, caches and renews Kerberos tickets for user
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/kdestroy -q -c /tmp/krb5cc_%U
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kinit -V -l 30d -r 365d -k -t %h/client.keytab -c /tmp/krb5cc_%U %i@EXAMPLE.COM
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/krenew -b -K 60 -k /tmp/krb5cc_%U
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=KerberosTicketing

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This works perfectly, and creates and stores the Kerberos authentication tickets if the `After` points to `default.target`. However, why `default.target`? That is quite late in the boot process. I would rather have it work at `multi-user.target`, so that I can use the generated tickets to mount remote file systems from servers that do not accept public/private authentication.

**EDIT**: If the `After` is anything but `default.target` or later, `kinit` fails with the error `kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "EXAMPLE.COM" while getting initial credentials`.

I am basically trying to accomplish this: [SSHFS automount through FSTAB using Kerberos (GSSAPI)](https://superuser.com/q/1354668/520328).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *systemd --user* units, that's where the time starts. **The entire --user manager** starts late in the boot process – it is a system service (user@.service) which is started by systemd-logind, which itself always starts during late boot.

To order the service against earlier units (like remote-fs.target), you need to convert this to a *system* service. Then your .mount units (or your fstab entries) will be able to specify dependencies on your service, as well.

---

Note that WantedBy= **does not** define when your unit will be queued (in a way it does the opposite). Instead, that is defined by the (implicit and explicit) Before=/After= options. It is perfectly possible and common to have a unit with "WantedBy=multi-user.target", but also "DefaultDependencies=no" and "Before=remote-fs.target".

---

As a side note, **do not** run daemons such as `krenew -K` via ExecStartPost=. The only place that 'officially' allows long-running processes (and provides such features as Restart=) is the main ExecStart=, so if you want periodic renewal, put your `krenew -K` there.

You can run kinit as a second ExecStartPre=, or use `k5start -K` which will avoid the need to manually kinit.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/k5start -L -b -K 30 -f %h/client.keytab -k /tmp/krb5cc_%U -u %i@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: Cool! Actually, my `systemd` `unit` file works with your `ExecStart`, and `After=multi-user.target`. So problem solved! I missed the `-b` flag of `k5start`, and therefore spent all this time on the goose chase. Thanks a million!

Comment: **After=** multi-user.target? That doesn't make sense according to your original question. It makes the service start _later_ than normal units do (even the 'late' ones are implicitly ordered before that target).

Comment: You need to review the service types that you use. Regular `k5start` is a long-running foreground process, which would have worked with `Type=simple`. If you use `k5start -b`, that makes it attempt to 'daemonize', which requires `Type=forking`. Neither of those is compatible with `Type=oneshot` (which is for momentary services which for example just do a quick kinit and nothing more).

Comment: So, even after converting to a system service, it does not start before `multi-user.target`. I get the Cannot find KDC for realm errors. Therefore, the only way it works is `After=multi-user.target`. I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Well, if it needs network, you need to order it **after the service which brings up network.** (Although ordering after multi-user.target does that in a broad sweep, it creates another problem – all .mounts are started long before this target, so now your service will run too late for sshfs to use it.) You may need `DefaultDependencies=no`, `Before=remote-fs-pre.target`, `After=network-online.target`, `Wants=network-online.target`. (All of them. Although note that network-online varies between distros.)

Comment: Yeah, I did that. On Ubuntu, `network.target` covers all network going up. Still, no dice. I did not try `DefaultDependencies` and `Before=remote-fs-pre.target`. Currently, I have the `sshfs` as a `bash` alias, and I run it manually.

Comment: My end goal is to have Kerberos tickets at system boot, and to be able to mount a remote directory. The Kerberos tickets are also used to SSH into the cluster with the remote storage. The desktop I am using is shared with another user in my team. Therefore, it is better that I stick to my userspace, and not do anything globally. Moreover, my colleague also would need to setup their own Kerberos authentication to the cluster, and mount their remote working directory as well.

Comment: But you were talking about mounting filesystems before multi-user.target. That is **already global**, as it's something that only happens through the system-wide fstab or .mount units. On the other hand, if you instead plan on doing your mounts through ~/.config/systemd/user/sshfs@.service (non-global), then multi-user.target has no relevance whatsoever and your original question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I want to do something like that. I am confused myself now. Do you recommend a resource where I can read and educate myself? Maybe then I can ask a better question. The problem I was facing when I wrote this question is that `After=default.target` was very late in the boot process. That did not leave anywhere to put a `sshfs@.service` between the `k5start@.service` and `default.target`. Now, with your help, I can use `After=multi-user.target`, which gives space to slot a `sshfs@service`. Thanks for the tip about `Type=forking`.

Comment: What do you mean by "space to slot"? **There are no slots.** If you have two services ordered after the same target, that _does not mean_ there couldn't be internal ordering between those two services. You could've just used something like `After=k5start@....service` in your sshfs service, without caring about targets at all. I think you're imagining After= as a strict "this will happen *right next* with no exceptions", but that's not what it is. It doesn't build a linked list; it builds a dependency tree and is a bit more flexible than you think.

Comment: No, I tried it. I got an error which I don't remember now. But it deleted the `sshfs@.service`. I don't mean slots literally. I understand the difference between a linked list and a dependency tree. I don't know how flexible the tree is though. The problem was `k5start@.service` was after `default.target` and `sshfs@.service` had `After=k5start.service`, but was wanted by `default.target` in Install. I know that services can depend on other services, not just targets.